# AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P to jpeg conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg

i am able to convert image from AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P to jpeg format (below Code) but the resultant image having green shade on complete bottom half plz suggest where i am doing wrong.
Following step i have taken

1. Initially i have AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422 image from camera, i have convert it in AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P format and able to see this image on http://rawpixels.net/ the parameters shown by website is size 2448X2050, Bpp1= 8,Bpp2 = 8 and Bpp3 = 8,alignment 1, SubSampling H =2, and SubSampling V = 1, format: YUV422P
   so input image is Correct AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P format. & also able to see on "YUV image viewer Software" using YUV422 format.
2. Now i am trying to convert it in jpeg format using below Code and attached is the resultant Image having green shade on complete bottom half.

   ```
       AVFormatContext*    pFormatCtx;
       AVOutputFormat*     fmt;
       AVStream*           video_st;
       AVCodecContext*     pCodecCtx;
       AVCodec*            pCodec;

       uint8_t*            picture_buf;
       AVFrame*            picture;
       AVPacket            pkt;
       int                 y_size;
       int                 size;
       int                 got_picture=0;  
       int                 ret=0;

   int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
   {

       FILE *in_file                       =   NULL;   
       unsigned int        in_width        =   2448;    
       unsigned int        in_height       =   2050;   
       const char* out_file                =   "encoded_pic.jpg";    


           in_file =   fopen("c:\\test_Planar.yuv","rb");
           if(in_file == NULL) { printf("\n\tFile Opening error...!!"); exit(1); }
           else printf("\n\tYUV File Open Sucessfully...!!\n\n");

           av_register_all();  // Loads the whole database of available codecs and formats.

           pFormatCtx          =   avformat_alloc_context();           
           fmt             =   NULL;
           fmt             =   av_guess_format("mjpeg",NULL,NULL);
           pFormatCtx->oformat     =   fmt;

   //------Output URL-------------------------
   if (avio_open(&pFormatCtx->pb,out_file, AVIO_FLAG_READ_WRITE) < 0)
   {
       printf("Couldn't open output file.");
       return -1;
   }

   video_st = avformat_new_stream(pFormatCtx, 0);    
   if (video_st==NULL)        return -1;


   pCodecCtx               =   video_st->codec;
   pCodecCtx->codec_id     =   fmt->video_codec;
   pCodecCtx->codec_type   =   AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
   pCodecCtx->pix_fmt      =   AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P;

   //--------------------------MY SOURCE PIXEL FORMAT--------------

   pCodecCtx->width        =   in_width;
   pCodecCtx->height       =   in_height;

   pCodecCtx->time_base.num = 1;
   pCodecCtx->time_base.den = 1;//25;

   //Output some information
   av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, out_file, 1);

   // Determine if desired video encoder is installed 
   pCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);

   if (!pCodec)
   {
       printf("Codec not found.");
       return -1;
   }

   printf("\nCodec Identified done\n");

   if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec,NULL) < 0){
       printf("Could not open codec.\n");
       return -1;
   }
   picture     =   av_frame_alloc();
   size            =   avpicture_get_size(pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
   picture_buf     =   (uint8_t *)av_malloc(size);
   if (!picture_buf)    return -1;

   avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)picture, picture_buf, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

   printf("\t\nWrite Header..");
   avformat_write_header(pFormatCtx,NULL);
   y_size = pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height;
   av_new_packet(&pkt,y_size*3);


   //Read YUV
   if (fread(picture_buf, 1, y_size*3/2, in_file) <=0)
   {
       printf("Could not read input file.");
       return -1;
   }
    //--------------------------------------------input image format UYVY
   picture->data[0] = picture_buf;             // Y
   picture->data[1] = picture_buf+ y_size;         // U
   picture->data[2] = picture_buf+ y_size*5/4;     // V
   //-----------------------------------------------

   printf("\t\n Encode the image..\n");
   ret = avcodec_encode_video2(pCodecCtx, &pkt,picture, &got_picture);
   if(ret < 0)
   {
       printf("Encode Error.\n");
       return -1;
   }

   if (got_picture==1)
   {
       pkt.stream_index = video_st->index;
       ret = av_write_frame(pFormatCtx, &pkt);
   }

   av_free_packet(&pkt);
   //Write Trailer
   av_write_trailer(pFormatCtx);    
   printf("Encode Successful.\n");

   if (video_st)
   {
       avcodec_close(video_st->codec);
       av_free(picture);
       av_free(picture_buf);
   }

   avio_close(pFormatCtx->pb);
   avformat_free_context(pFormatCtx);    

       fclose(in_file);
       printf("\n\tYUV File Close Sucessfully...!!");    
   }
   ```

[Resultant output jpeg encoded image from yuvj422p image having green shade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKLZ6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the input Pixel format from AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P to AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ**420**P resolve the issue.